# Trying to find error why map isn't centered when resize window

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using a dom listener to set the center of the map when a user is resizing the window, but i'm confused because nothing happens!? What have I missed? Every thing else works fine with the map in responsive design. Help is preciated.

If someone is wondering why I have this code `{$mapPoints}` this is a PHP string of all markers.

EDIT 2: 
At start I have the markers in the center of the map. Then I pan the map and the markers isn't in the center any more. When I resize the window I want the markers at the center of the map as it was from the beginning (55.678939, 12.568359). Have I miss understodd something or isn't this possible? I have also tried to set the center of the map to the these coordinates when resizing the window.

EDIT 1:

CSS for the map:

```
#map_canvas
{
width: 100%;
height: 350px;
margin: 20px 0 20px 0px;
}

var map = null;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var iconBase = 'images/mapNumbers/number';

function initialize() {

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.678939, 12.568359),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
    infowindow.close();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
infowindow.close();
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
//map.setCenter(55.678939, 12.568359);
var center = map.getCenter();
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
map.setCenter(center); 
});

// Add markers to the map
var point;
{$mapPoints}
 }

 // Create markers
function createMarker(latlng, html, name, number) {

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
title: name,
icon: iconBase + number + '.png'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infowindow.setContent(html);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
//map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
});

}

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: What is styling of `map_canvas`? Is it in % or fixed values?

Comment: Does your window resize event listener function get triggered when the window resizes?  Do you correctly get the map center coordinates when that happens?

Comment: FYI: I used your code, added some logs and map event listener for `resize` and I cannot see problem at all (I used fixed and % width for map). If I drag the map, information about center is changed.

Comment: Thanks for all comments! I added the CSS for the map if that could be of any help, because I can't find the reason why it isn't working!? :(

Comment: @duncan I added a simple alert message to see if the event listener was triggered, and I got a message when I resized the window. And I also got the center coordinates in the alert message. I'm very confused why this isn't working. Any more clues?

Comment: @AntoJurković Please see my second edit above. I have tested all kinds of things to get this to work. I added a alert message to check if the event was triggered, and it was. I'm using a width with % and a a height in px. Any more clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that at the beginning you almost got it right. I did the following changes:

```
function initialize() {
    var markerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(55.678939, 12.568359);

var myOptions = {
    center: markerPos,
    ...
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerPos,
    ...
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
    console.log('window resize');

    map.setCenter(markerPos);

    var center = map.getCenter();
    console.log(center);
    // google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

Test should be like you wrote: load the map, pan to the left/right, resize the window. Marker and the map should be centered.

Comment: Great! Now it's working like I want it to do! I'm just curious and would like to know why it's working now? What was the main difference and why? Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @3D-kreativ Before: center was changed and you just retrieve new value and set the same new value back. Now: old value of center is set in each case. You had that line in your original code but it was commented out. And also when you post your question I did not understand what was your problem. With your update it was clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the bounds_changed event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
  //do really cool stuff and change the world or at least a map of it
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working :( What could be wrong? Preciate some help with this problem. It can't be that complicated, I guess I have just missed something!?